# IoT Industrial Cloudless Architecture

Tags: azure, architecture, cloud, iot, industrial

For school, I have to make an assignment to design a cloudless IoT infrastructure. I've researched other architectures, but most of them use the cloud. Now my question was how I can remove the cloud from the architecture, and where is the data stored? I already made an example of what I think it should look like:

[image: This is the architecture I have now designed.]

I'm curious about the opinions and tips.

Comment: What does that even mean, cloudless? If you can't use a cloud service provider like AWS, Azure, etc., it means that you'll have to host everything yourself. If you can't use the cloud (Internet) at all, it means that you'll have to host everything yourself and need to set up a private network.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Indeed, that is the purpose of the assignment. The architecture should not be connected to the internet. And it is indeed true that a private network must be set up.

Comment: what about something like Edge computing? It can run everything locally and mostly disconnected, but for management you use the cloud? e.g Azure IoT Edge https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/about-iot-edge?view=iotedge-2020-11#iot-edge-runtime

Comment: @silent I looked at that, but you don't want to save all the machine data on an Edge Device, it seems to me, you want to save the data somewhere else and then not in the Cloud is the intention.